# Web page resizing breaks menu item

Tags: css, web, html

I am developing a website and the problem is that when I resize the browser (horizontaly), my HOME link from the menu gets broken. It's harder to explain in words what happens, so check it out here: http://www-user.tu-cottbus.de/~carbusor/Red%20Diamond/html/index.html.

The grey background is an image, having the up-right corner cut. After I cut that area, I made the area transparent. So, it is a trapezoid on transparent background.

My question is: what to do to prevent the trapezoid transforming into a rectangle when resizing?

Answer (score 0):

If you want something like that.
[image]

Where the diamond is in between the two tabs then you should give particular width to your li elements(All).not use percentages for that. Like this

```
 .menu > li#home {
 display: inline;
 float: left;
 background: none;
 background-image: url(../img/home.png);
 width: 273px;   /* same as your image size */
 }
```

and also to both of your header images

```
img#logo {
position: absolute;
top: 10px;  /* Change it as it sets in the gap */
left: 250px; /* Change it as it sets in the gap */
width: 140px;
height: 90px;
}
```

Comment: I don't like what's happening. Some menu items disappear.

Comment: if you paste the html and css of your page here or give a fiddle. Then i can resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using an image, create the shape you want right in the file.  Try this link:

[Using the Area Shape Attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_area_shape.asp)